# ¿”Para ella y yo” o “para ella y mí”?

Tags: pronombres

Cuando hay más que un objeto para una preposición, ¿todos los pronombres toman la forma preposicional? ¿O solo la primera?

Como dice el título, me gustaría saber cuál de estas opciones es más correcta:

1. “para ella y yo”. Solo el primer pronombre tomaría la forma preposicional. (Aunque en este ejemplo “ella” es tanto la forma preposicional como la nominal.)
2. “para ella y mí”. Todos los pronombres toman la forma preposicional.
3. “para ella y para mí”. Quizás se suele evitar  este problema repitiendo la preposición.

Comment: Esta pregunta me pareció sumamente interesante; por una vez el instinto de hablante nativo me falló totalmente. Gracias.

Comment: Me alegra que hayas podido ayudar - ni yo ni mi esposa sabíamos la respuesta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La opción correcta es la 3, “para ella y para mí”. Lo explica la *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española*:

> **[16.3d](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SuFkqVFHbfgkIqyU)** (...) los pronombres oblicuos coordinados no comparten una misma preposición en el español actual. Se dice, por tanto, *para ti y para mí*, pero no **para ti y mí*. (...) Esta restricción pone de manifiesto que el caso de estos pronombres no se extiende al grupo coordinado que constituyen (...).

En este punto se refiere a [otro apartado](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SMpBOBEopZzAJiIO), cuya captura copio aquí:

[image: 31.4k]